# Projected coordinate in TikZ is not properly placed

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to draw an airplane.  When I was drawing the window for the cockpit, I was using projected points to get right angles.  But things aren't working out as expected.  Could anyone give me a pointer about what I'm doing incorrectly?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\def\aeBodyRadius{0.25cm}
\def\aeBodyNoseDistance{0.21cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=5cm,y=5cm,scale=3,every node={transform shape}]

  \coordinate (TAIL) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (NOSE) at ($(TAIL)+(30:1)$);

  \coordinate (MID)     at ($(TAIL)!0.75!(NOSE)$);

  \coordinate (MID/TOP) at ($(MID)!\aeBodyRadius!90:(NOSE)$);
  \coordinate (MID/BOT) at ($(MID)!\aeBodyRadius!-90:(NOSE)$);

  \coordinate (NOSE/TIP) at ($(NOSE)!\aeBodyNoseDistance!90:(MID)$);

  \coordinate (HIND/TOP) at ($(TAIL)!\aeBodyRadius!90:(NOSE)$);
  \coordinate (HIND/BOT) at ($(TAIL)!\aeBodyRadius!-90:(NOSE)$);

  \node[fill,circle,inner sep=1pt] at (MID/TOP) {};
  \node[fill,circle,inner sep=1pt] at (MID/BOT) {};
  \node[fill,circle,inner sep=1pt] at (HIND/TOP) {};
  \node[fill,circle,inner sep=1pt] at (HIND/BOT) {};

  \draw[rounded corners=10pt] 
                             (HIND/TOP) --
                             (MID/TOP)  --
                             node [pos=0.25] (WINDOW/TOP/N) {}
                             node [pos=0.50] (WINDOW/BOT/N) {}
                             (NOSE/TIP) -- 
                             (MID/BOT)  --
                             (HIND/BOT);
    \coordinate (WINDOW/TOP) at (WINDOW/TOP/N.center);
    \coordinate (WINDOW/BOT) at (WINDOW/BOT/N.center);

    \coordinate (WINDOW/RIG/T) at ($(TAIL)!(WINDOW/TOP)!(NOSE)$);
    \coordinate (WINDOW/RIG)   at ($(WINDOW/TOP)!(WINDOW/BOT)!(WINDOW/RIG/T)$);

    \draw (WINDOW/TOP) -- (WINDOW/RIG) -- (WINDOW/BOT);

    \draw[red] (TAIL) -- (NOSE);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The "red" line runs down the center of the plane clearly shows how my *perpendicular* is not what it should be.

*UPDATE*

What seems *not* to be working is the following snippet of code:

```
    \coordinate (WINDOW/RIG/T) at ($(TAIL)!(WINDOW/TOP)!(NOSE)$);
    \coordinate (WINDOW/RIG)   at ($(WINDOW/TOP)!(WINDOW/BOT)!(WINDOW/RIG/T)$);
```

The projected points do not seem to lie on the appropriate perpendicular.  In particular,
`(WINDOW/RIG)` should lie above the red line since the line through `(WINDOW/TOP)` and `(WINDOW/RIG/T)` should be perpendicular to the red line through `(TAIL)` and `(NOSE)`.

Comment: Are you calling the concorde an airplane? What a shame :P

Comment: @percusse  Well actually it's suppose to be an Airbus.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you think is wrong.  You start with `NOSE` and `TAIL` and everything seems relative to those two points. Not sure where you expected the red line to be?

Comment: @PeterGrill I've added an update.  I'll be away from the computer for about an hour and a half.  When I get back I'll try to clean up the code a bit to make it more readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by [A.Ellett](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168120/projected-coordinate-in-tikz-is-not-properly-placed#comment413250_168249), the error is caused by `\pgfpointnormalised`. A solution to obtain a better precision is given in this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/334243/right-angle-mark-not-drawn-correctly/334267#334267).

Applied on the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pagestyle{empty}

% use the Mark Wibrow's correction
\makeatletter
\def\pgfpointnormalised#1{%
\pgf@process{#1}%
\pgfmathatantwo{\the\pgf@y}{\the\pgf@x}%
\let\pgf@tmp=\pgfmathresult%
\pgfmathcos@{\pgf@tmp}\pgf@x=\pgfmathresult pt\relax%
\pgfmathsin@{\pgf@tmp}\pgf@y=\pgfmathresult pt\relax%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\def\aeBodyRadius{0.25cm}
\def\aeBodyNoseDistance{0.21cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=5cm,y=5cm,scale=3,every node={transform shape}]

  \coordinate (TAIL) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (NOSE) at ($(TAIL)+(30:1)$);

  \coordinate (MID)     at ($(TAIL)!0.75!(NOSE)$);

  \coordinate (MID/TOP) at ($(MID)!\aeBodyRadius!90:(NOSE)$);
  \coordinate (MID/BOT) at ($(MID)!\aeBodyRadius!-90:(NOSE)$);

  \coordinate (NOSE/TIP) at ($(NOSE)!\aeBodyNoseDistance!90:(MID)$);

  \coordinate (HIND/TOP) at ($(TAIL)!\aeBodyRadius!90:(NOSE)$);
  \coordinate (HIND/BOT) at ($(TAIL)!\aeBodyRadius!-90:(NOSE)$);

  \node[fill,circle,inner sep=1pt] at (MID/TOP) {};
  \node[fill,circle,inner sep=1pt] at (MID/BOT) {};
  \node[fill,circle,inner sep=1pt] at (HIND/TOP) {};
  \node[fill,circle,inner sep=1pt] at (HIND/BOT) {};

  \draw[rounded corners=10pt] 
                             (HIND/TOP) --
                             (MID/TOP)  --
                             node [pos=0.25] (WINDOW/TOP/N) {}
                             node [pos=0.50] (WINDOW/BOT/N) {}
                             (NOSE/TIP) -- 
                             (MID/BOT)  --
                             (HIND/BOT);
    \coordinate (WINDOW/TOP) at (WINDOW/TOP/N.center);
    \coordinate (WINDOW/BOT) at (WINDOW/BOT/N.center);

    \coordinate (WINDOW/RIG/T) at ($(TAIL)!(WINDOW/TOP)!(NOSE)$);
    \coordinate (WINDOW/RIG)   at ($(WINDOW/TOP)!(WINDOW/BOT)!(WINDOW/RIG/T)$);

    \draw (WINDOW/TOP) -- (WINDOW/RIG) -- (WINDOW/BOT);

    \draw[red] (TAIL) -- (NOSE);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The solution is from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/256333/drawing-the-three-altitudes-of-a-triangle-with-tikz-incorrect-orthocenter/256377#256377 - fairer to link to the horse's mouth, I'd suggest.

Comment: This has been fixed upstream: https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/git/ci/65b8261c63c6f4adfca60106528e2d1bf1e2cb60/

Answer (score 3):

You probably intended to put WINDOW/RIG/T along the main axis, but this worked.  (If it aint broke...)

[image: vvvooooom!]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\def\aeBodyRadius{0.25cm}
\def\aeBodyNoseDistance{0.21cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=5cm,y=5cm,scale=3,every node={transform shape}]
  \coordinate (TAIL) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (NOSE) at ($(TAIL)+(30:1)$);
  \coordinate (MID)     at ($(TAIL)!0.75!(NOSE)$);
  \coordinate (MID/TOP) at ($(MID)!\aeBodyRadius!90:(NOSE)$);
  \coordinate (MID/BOT) at ($(MID)!\aeBodyRadius!-90:(NOSE)$);
  \coordinate (NOSE/TIP) at ($(NOSE)!\aeBodyNoseDistance!90:(MID)$);
  \coordinate (HIND/TOP) at ($(TAIL)!\aeBodyRadius!90:(NOSE)$);
  \coordinate (HIND/BOT) at ($(TAIL)!\aeBodyRadius!-90:(NOSE)$);
  \node[fill,circle,inner sep=1pt] at (MID/TOP) {};
  \node[fill,circle,inner sep=1pt] at (MID/BOT) {};
  \node[fill,circle,inner sep=1pt] at (HIND/TOP) {};
  \node[fill,circle,inner sep=1pt] at (HIND/BOT) {};
  \draw[rounded corners=10pt] 
                             (HIND/TOP) --
                             (MID/TOP)  --
                             node [pos=0.25] (WINDOW/TOP/N) {}
                             node [pos=0.50] (WINDOW/BOT/N) {}
                             (NOSE/TIP) -- 
                             (MID/BOT)  --
                             (HIND/BOT);
  \coordinate (WINDOW/TOP) at (WINDOW/TOP/N.center);
  \coordinate (WINDOW/BOT) at (WINDOW/BOT/N.center);

%start of modifications
   \coordinate (WINDOW/RIG/T) at ($(TAIL)!(WINDOW/TOP)!90:(NOSE)$);
   \coordinate (WINDOW/RIG)   at ($(WINDOW/TOP)!(WINDOW/BOT)!90:(WINDOW/RIG/T)$);
   \node[fill,circle,inner sep=1pt] at (WINDOW/RIG/T) {};% way down near the tail
   \draw[blue] (WINDOW/TOP) -- (WINDOW/RIG) -- (WINDOW/BOT);
%end of modifications

   \draw[red] (TAIL) -- (NOSE);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I hadn't thought of that.  +1 for now.  Though I'd be interested in knowing why projection itself didn't give the correct result.

Comment: While this is something of a solution, it misses the point that the `calc` library's syntax of `($(A)!(B)!(C)$)` which should project `B` orthogonally onto line `AC` is not behaving as it should.  I've played with quite a bit now.  I think the issue has to do with rounding error.  In particular I think it has to do with how `\pgfpointnormalised` works.

Comment: @A.Ellett - You can also make it work if you draw it flat then rotate the image by 30 degrees, so you are probably right.

Answer (score 1):

To show what I meant by drawing it flat and rotating it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pagestyle{empty}

\newlength{\myx}
\newlength{\myy}

\begin{document}
\def\aeBodyRadius{0.25cm}
\def\aeBodyNoseDistance{0.21cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=5cm,y=5cm,scale=3,every node={transform shape},rotate=30]% changed here
  \coordinate (TAIL) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (NOSE) at ($(TAIL)+(1,0)$);% changed here
  \coordinate (MID)     at ($(TAIL)!0.75!(NOSE)$);
  \coordinate (MID/TOP) at ($(MID)!\aeBodyRadius!90:(NOSE)$);
  \coordinate (MID/BOT) at ($(MID)!\aeBodyRadius!-90:(NOSE)$);
  \coordinate (NOSE/TIP) at ($(NOSE)!\aeBodyNoseDistance!90:(MID)$);
  \coordinate (HIND/TOP) at ($(TAIL)!\aeBodyRadius!90:(NOSE)$);
  \coordinate (HIND/BOT) at ($(TAIL)!\aeBodyRadius!-90:(NOSE)$);
  \node[fill,circle,inner sep=1pt] at (MID/TOP) {};
  \node[fill,circle,inner sep=1pt] at (MID/BOT) {};
  \node[fill,circle,inner sep=1pt] at (HIND/TOP) {};
  \node[fill,circle,inner sep=1pt] at (HIND/BOT) {};
  \draw[rounded corners=10pt] 
                             (HIND/TOP) --
                             (MID/TOP)  --
                             node [pos=0.25] (WINDOW/TOP/N) {}
                             node [pos=0.50] (WINDOW/BOT/N) {}
                             (NOSE/TIP) -- 
                             (MID/BOT)  --
                             (HIND/BOT);
  \coordinate (WINDOW/TOP) at (WINDOW/TOP/N.center);
  \coordinate (WINDOW/BOT) at (WINDOW/BOT/N.center);

  \node[fill,circle,inner sep=1pt] at (NOSE) {};
  \node[fill,circle,inner sep=1pt] at (TAIL) {};
  \coordinate (WINDOW/RIG/T) at ($(TAIL)!(WINDOW/TOP)!(NOSE)$);
  \coordinate (WINDOW/RIG)   at ($(WINDOW/TOP)!(WINDOW/BOT)!(WINDOW/RIG/T)$);
  \node[fill,circle,inner sep=1pt] at (WINDOW/RIG/T) {};
  \draw[blue] (WINDOW/TOP) -- (WINDOW/RIG) -- (WINDOW/BOT);
  \draw[red] (TAIL) -- (NOSE);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: rotated]