# TikZ coordinate calculation accuracy

Tags: tikz-pgf

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[join=bevel]
   \draw (0,0) coordinate (B) -- (6,0) coordinate (C)  
        -- (6,4.5) coordinate (A) -- cycle;
   \coordinate (F) at ($(A)!(C)!(B)$);
   \draw (C) -- (B) -- (0,8) coordinate (D)  -- cycle;
   \draw[fill=gray] (D) -- (A) -- (F) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

It yields
[image]

However, the corner of the gray triangle should be exactly on the line from the top left to the lower right corner. (This can be easily verified with GeoGebra or by calculation.)

Why does this happen?

Comment: This is a known issue with clac projection, see for example [Error in projection modifier with tikz calc?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/271476/59109) .

Comment: Thanks, I have never seen that before, even though I do a lot of geometry stuff with TikZ. Will there be a fix for this? I would call it a bug.

Comment: The corresponding feature request is marked for "next release", but when that is I have no idea: https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/feature-requests/96/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As pointed out by Mark Wibrow in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/256377/9335) the definition of `\pgfpointnormalised` can be corrected to obtain better precision.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, spy}

% use the Mark Wibrow's correction
\makeatletter
\def\pgfpointnormalised#1{%
  \pgf@process{#1}%
  \pgfmathatantwo{\the\pgf@y}{\the\pgf@x}%
  \let\pgf@tmp=\pgfmathresult%
  \pgfmathcos@{\pgf@tmp}\pgf@x=\pgfmathresult pt\relax%
  \pgfmathsin@{\pgf@tmp}\pgf@y=\pgfmathresult pt\relax%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[join=bevel, spy using outlines={circle, magnification=7, size=17mm, connect spies}]
   \draw (0,0) coordinate (B) -- (6,0) coordinate (C)
        -- (6,4.5) coordinate (A) -- cycle;
   \coordinate (F) at ($(A)!(C)!(B)$);
   \draw (C) -- (B) -- (0,8) coordinate (D)  -- cycle;
   \draw[fill=gray] (D) -- (A) -- (F) -- cycle;

   \spy[red] on (F) in node at (1,2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Note :** This is a copy of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/334267/9335).

Comment: This has been fixed upstream: https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/git/ci/65b8261c63c6f4adfca60106528e2d1bf1e2cb60/