# Can polar coordinates cause misalignment in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to align two paths using polar coordinates:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \path [fill=blue] (0,0) -- +(-135:5mm) -- ([turn]90:25mm) -- ([turn]90:5mm) -- cycle;
    \path [fill=red] (0,0) -- +(-135:5mm) -- ([turn]90: 5mm) -- ([turn]90:5mm) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

However, they are slightly misaligned:

(The picture below is cropped and zoomed in)

[image]

Am I missing, i.e. miscalculating something here?

Comment: What a funny coincidence to hear from you first. Just an hour ago I came across your name when learning about tikzlings :). The output is cropped and zoomed to the critical location, it's incomplete. I'm using pdflatex from MacTeX 2018.

Comment: I can not answer, but it does not happen, if you avoid `[turn]` e.g. `\path [fill=blue] (0,0) -- ++(-135:5mm) -- ++(-45:25mm) -- ++(45:5mm) -- cycle;`

Comment: It doesn't seem that polar coordinates are the reason since `\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \path [fill=blue] (0,0) -- ++(-135:5mm) -- 
 ++ (-45:25mm) -- ++ (45:5mm) -- cycle;
    \path [fill=red] (0,0) -- ++(-135:5mm) -- 
 ++ (-45: 5mm) -- ++(45:5mm) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}` has no such problem. Rather, this might be due to `turn`.

Comment: @marmot: I was 3 second faster :o)

Comment: @hpekristiansen Yes, which is why I upvoted your comment. (Mine may still be somewhat useful because one can immediately compile it.)

Comment: Thanks to the both of you, at least that's a workaround. I'll create an issue for `turn`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is this old [inaccuracies in PGF](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/256377) pointed long time ago by Mark Wibrow. If we apply its correction of `\pgfpointnormalised` we obtain a better precision not only for the orthogonal projections but also for `[turn]`.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}

% use the Mark Wibrow's correction
\makeatletter
\def\pgfpointnormalised#1{%
  \pgf@process{#1}%
  \pgfmathatantwo{\the\pgf@y}{\the\pgf@x}%
  \let\pgf@tmp=\pgfmathresult%
  \pgfmathcos@{\pgf@tmp}\pgf@x=\pgfmathresult pt\relax%
  \pgfmathsin@{\pgf@tmp}\pgf@y=\pgfmathresult pt\relax%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[spy using outlines={circle, magnification=7, size=17mm, connect spies}]

    \path [draw=blue] (0,0) -- +(-135:5mm) -- ([turn]90:25mm) -- ([turn]90:5mm) -- cycle;
    \path [draw=red] (0,0) -- +(-135:5mm) -- ([turn]90: 5mm) -- ([turn]90:5mm) -- cycle;

    \spy on (-45:5mm) in node at (2,-.5);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1: Do you know if this "bug" is officially reported?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner this is not an easy "bug" because by design `\pgfpointnormalised` is not supposed to be really precise in direction, but it is designed to really have length `1pt` (as described in the manual). The problem is that it is used in places where the precision in direction is important ... I'll check if this is discussed in SourceForge.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner this "bug" is [reported](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/519/) now.

Comment: Thanks! I do not understand the technicalities but I appreciate the effort.

Comment: This has been fixed upstream: https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/git/ci/65b8261c63c6f4adfca60106528e2d1bf1e2cb60/